# Can I make a context menu entry for MicrosoftTeams like Polly or Forms

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to add my own entry to the context menu of Microsoft Teams, like Polly or Forms.
[image: Like This]

I want there an entry like: "Send this as Mail" and if i click it, it should send this message as a mail on my mailbox.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is something called "Messaging Extension" - see more in the docs about what it is and how to build it over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions).

Worth being aware of:

1. These basically require a Bot behind the scenes, so if you've not built one of those before, have a look at the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/).
2. There are actually 3 kinds of Message Extensions - the one you're looking for is one that goes on the "Action" list for an individual message, essentially a "message" message extension, but there's also the ability to add something into the main text box on the bottom in Teams, and the ability to add a command into the "Command box" right at the very top of Teams. All of these are achieved using "message extensions", just as an fyi

Comment: Thank you very much dude. I've heard about Messaging Extensions and have a bot already, but didn't know that the Messaging Extensions are the menu options. aprecciate it.